# How to connect PHP to DBF file using the ODBC method

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I have an `dbf` file. I would like to use PHP to read data out of this `dbf` file using the ODBC connection method.

I am using xampp to test this.

I have set up the ODBC. Here is the ODBC connection.

[image: odbc settings 1]

[image: odbc settings 2]

```php
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('TestDBF','');
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Failed";
}
?>
```

This is the error I get:

[image: PHP Error]

The dbf file is saved on the desktop. How I can use PHP script to use ODBC connection to read data out of this file?*

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right php doesn't handle dbf out of the box and you need to install an extension or find a version that has been compiled with that capability. THis may have changed though as the last time I used it was in the php 5.x days.

Also there are difference versions of dbf, so you need to make sure yours is compatible with whatever extesion/driver you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> How to connect PHP to DBF file using the ODBC method?

Try this:

```
<?php
    /* Microsoft SQL Server using the SQL Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver */
    $odbc = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};
                         Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

    // Microsoft Access
    $odbc = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
                          Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);

    // Microsoft Excel
    $excelFile = realpath('C:/ExcelData.xls');
    $excelDir = dirname($excelFile);
    $odbc = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};
                        DriverId=790;Dbq=$excelFile;DefaultDir=$excelDir" , '', '');
?>
```

Comment: It's not access file or excel file. I've got the dbf file. I tried all the above prior to posting question on here.